# Xamarin UWP : app in front/rear (method unexisting ?)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have a app in xamarin that listen a folder and do some action when a file is created.
But the thing is that I need to be able to :

1. bring my app in front when a file is created
2. push my app in rear when acyion are finished

I have a beginning of response with

```
Window.Current.Activate();
```

but that only work if my app is not minimize (app not in first view)
I've already tried this :

```
IList<AppDiagnosticInfo> infos = await AppDiagnosticInfo.RequestInfoForAppAsync();
IList<AppResourceGroupInfo> resourceInfos = infos[0].GetResourceGroups();
await resourceInfos[0].StartSuspendAsync();
```

but visual studio tell me

> AppResourceGroupInfo don't have a definition for StartSuspendAsync()

but documentation mention it [AppResourceGroupInfo.StartSuspendAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.appresourcegroupinfo.startsuspendasync?view=winrt-18362)

someone have an idea ?

UPDATE [2020-04-29 16:48] :

- This is a pcl project
- the intention is to use dependency service to have diferent comportement in function of platform (already implemented just need the front/rear

interface in pcl

```
public interface IWindowManager
    {
        void Minimize();
        void Maximize();
    }
```

in uwp

```cs
class WindowManager : IWindowManager
    {
        public async void Maximize()
        {
            try
            {
                Window.Current.Activate();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                DependencyService.Get<IErrorLogger>().LogError(ex);
            }
        }

        public async void Minimize()
        {
            IList<AppDiagnosticInfo> infos = await AppDiagnosticInfo.RequestInfoForAppAsync();
            IList<AppResourceGroupInfo> resourceInfos = infos[0].GetResourceGroups();
            resourceInfos[0].StartSuspendAsync();
        }
    }
```

and as I say StartSuspendAsync() encounter some problem

Comment: where is this code ? is it in UWP project or shared?

Comment: I update my post with more structural detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AppResourceGroupInfo don't have a definition for StartSuspendAsync()

Derive from official document, `StartSuspendAsync()` available in the Windows 10 update 1803 (build 17134). So please edit the UWP project mini version to 17134.

> but that only work if my app is not minimize (app not in first view)

For making the app [foreground](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.core.applistentry.launchasync?view=winrt-18362), you could use the following code.

```
IEnumerable<AppListEntry> appListEntries = await Package.Current.GetAppListEntriesAsync();
        await appListEntries.First().LaunchAsync();
```

**Update**

If above does not work, please try use register a [protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation) for UWP app and launch it with `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync` method.

```
public async void Maximize()
{
    try
    {
        await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("testapp:"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: half correct : the first part is ok and suspendasync work correctly I will update my post afetr find the second part. for the second part I understand the logic but 'Package.Current.GetAppListEntriesAsync();' return my app (logic with package.current). the solution for that coul be packageManager (test in progress)

Comment: @GautierLogeot For the second part I often used in desktop extension app, and use above code to call the uwp to foreground. Could tell more detail about your scenario?

Comment: sorry problem of traduction from me. your code work almost perfectly (just a problem of acces that I'm working to solve)

Comment: when LaunchAsync() is called I have this exception : "Access Denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))". a capability to add ?

Comment: I mean, how do you call `LaunchAsync` method?

Comment: I use these 2 lines on an button for testing before integrating `DependencyService.Get<IWindowManager>().Minimize();
            Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(t => DependencyService.Get<IWindowManager>().Maximize());` and Maximize is just your 2 lines within a try/catch

Comment: it throw exception  when you call` DependencyService.Get<IWindowManager>().Maximize()` right?

Comment: in the Maximize() at  `await appListEntries.First().LaunchAsync();`

Comment: Could you share mini sample that could reproduce this issue. I will test base on your demo.

Comment: here you are : [git hub project MiniSample](https://github.com/werewolf7160/MiniSample)

Comment: Thank I will try whenever I have the time